# when clone a jquery object and save in it a javascript object, how can i access the contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have saved a div in a javascript object:

```
DYN = {}; 
DYN['mydiv'] = $('#my-div').clone(true);
```

How can I access the attributes of this javascript object directly with jquery. Do i Have to reload the #my-div div first, to access the attributes of the div, or ????

```
$("#my-div").replaceWith(DYN['mydiv']); 
$('#my-div').val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DYN['mydiv']` contains a jQuery object, you should be able to use jQuery methods on it.

```
alert( DYN['mydiv'].val() );
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5rB2X/

Comment: But how can i select something in the div, like the value of the nickname in: <input id="nickname" ... value="John" >

Comment: @voscausa the clone is not on the DOM and therefor the user can not interact with it.

Comment: @voscausa The clone is a document fragment, therefore if it has children, you can navigate to them just like you normally would. Keep in mind, however, that ID's must be unique. once you clone an element that has or contains element that have ID's, those ID's are no longer unique and need to be changed. http://jsfiddle.net/5rB2X/1/

Comment: I understand, but how add a selectot to the object? See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rB2X/

Comment: Again, you would do it just like any other time. Use `.append()` http://jsfiddle.net/5rB2X/4/

Comment: Thanks. That works. Do you always have to use the find method if you have to select something in the javascript object?

Comment: Yes unless you provide the javascript object as a context. `$("select", DYN['mydiv']).doSomething();`

Comment: Thanks again, and for the introduction to fiddle to share code. I normally use Chrome developer tools to edit and debug.